# How to open a fragment from a button click which is included in another layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, buttonclick, fragmenttransaction

Hello i want to open a fragment with button click but the button is in the layout snipet_profile.xml and i have included snipet_profile.xml in fragment_profile now when i click the button it dosent open the fragment that i wanted to be open ,Fragment which i want to open on button click is EditProfile

ok if you  think it is liitle bit confusing see my code

i have tried a method where first you have to find the layout which have the button in my case it is RelativeLayout so i implemented this way

**ProfleFragment.java**

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.snipet_profile); // R.id.snipet_profile is the layout that i have included in Profile Fragment
```

and now the button

```
Button editProfileButton;
editProfileButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_button); t// i have included relativelayout.findViewById so it can navigate or in simple this method i found
```

**Error** // after implementing the answer

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myappnotfinal, PID: 12566
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.myappnotfinal:layout/fragment_edit_profile: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.myappnotfinal:layout/fragment_edit_profile: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.myappnotfinal:layout/fragment_edit_profile: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.example.myappnotfinal.Fragments.Profile.Edit_Profile.onCreateView(Edit_Profile.java:23)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adjustViewBounds not supported.
        at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(CircleImageView.java:141)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:215)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:188)
        at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.<init>(CircleImageView.java:98)
        at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.<init>(CircleImageView.java:94)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538) 
        at com.example.myappnotfinal.Fragments.Profile.Edit_Profile.onCreateView(Edit_Profile.java:23) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Now the full code

**Profile_Fragment.java**

```
Button editProfileButton;
@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
    @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.snipet_profile);
        editProfileButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_button);
        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);// added this line of code according to the answer

        return view;
    }
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (view.getId() == R.id.edit_profile_button) {
            fragment = new Edit_Profile(); // Edit_Profile fragment
            replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(new Profile_Fragment()));
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/snipet_profile"
            layout="@layout/snipet_profile" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**snipet_profile.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Followers"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_red"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</Button>
```

**Update 1** // added EditProfile java and xml files

**Edit_Profile.java** // these is the fragment im trying to open on button click

```
public class Edit_Profile extends Fragment {
    private CircleImageView profilePhoto;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
        profilePhoto = view.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
        setProfileImage();
        initImageLoader();

        return view;
    }

    private void initImageLoader() {
        UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(getContext());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
    }

    private void setProfileImage() {
        String imgUrl = "https://64.media.tumblr.com/1276b4edef49034af70bda14325385e3/d8872c747cafa206-96/s500x750/aa915fc49a84b5295f0cd44145d655b66eb906a6.jpg";
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imgUrl, profilePhoto, null, "");
    }
}
```

**fragment_edit_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/done"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/change_profilePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/change_photo"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/change_profilePhoto"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/user_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:autofillHints="User Name"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/add"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/lite_grey"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userNameEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:autofillHints="ADD"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/add"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/lite_grey"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set `OnClickListener` for this `Button`... use `editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(this);` - `this` is used as your `Fragment implements View.OnClickListener`

edit: well, your stacktrace is saying everything...

```
IllegalArgumentException: adjustViewBounds not supported.
    at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(CircleImageView.java:141)
```

just remove `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` line from XML-declared `CircleImageView`. and also remove `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. read [THIS](https://www.studytonight.com/post/how-to-create-circleimageview-using-hdodenhof-in-android-app) article, in which you can find:

> The ScaleType of CircleImageView is always CENTER_CROP and if we try to change it we get an exception. So it is perfect for the profile pictures.

> Enabling adjustViewBounds is not supported as this requires an unsupported ScaleType

Comment: ok i have tried your solution now the app crash the error is  Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and the error is showing in my EditProfile , i will update my question with edit profile code

Comment: post full stacktrace and also fragments XML (`fragment_edit_profile`)

Comment: ok i have updated the question please check